# Can anyone help me identify this silver Chinese dragon dollar?

Tags: china, numismatics, qing-dynasty, silver

These coins were historically minted at the Nanking mint in Kiangnan province but the obverse of this coin appears to reference the "Zhejiang" mint. I've not been able to locate any other examples.

[image: An image of a silver Chinese dragon dollar]

Comment: Title is a [yes/no question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines); such questions seem to attract fewer answers and lower quality answers.  There is an implied question in the body about  [Zhejian mint](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/mint.php?id=4641) that might be stronger, but I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

As a first attempt, based on a rather limited knowledge of Chinese: In the middle, 光緒 is the name of the [Guangxu emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangxu_Emperor). 元寶 probably means something like coin or treasury. The small writing right in the middle is probably Manchu which I cannot read.

At the top, from right to left: 浙江省造 means "made in [Zhejiang province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhejiang)". Bottom looks to me like 庫平七錢二分, with the first and last characters both quite doubtful. Translation would be "7.2 cash according to the Kuping standard", I think.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty_coinage) lists Hangzhou in Zhejiang as one of a number of places where Qing-era coins were struck, so I do not see a problem with that place name. In fact googling for "庫平七錢二分" results in some images of very similar coins from Zhejiang, at least for me.